# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException how to solve?

Tags: java-7, glassfish-4

When i display image using `com.jsos.image.ImageServlet` then 
   my `glassfish 4.0` server fire this error please give me solution.

this is working perfectly in `java 6` and `glassfish 3`

My stacktrash is :

```
   [2014-03-07T08:32:38.465-0500] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1394199158465] [levelValue: 900] [[
      StandardWrapperValve[fileServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet fileServlet threw exception
    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:958)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:682)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
        at utilities.MobileVideoServlet.copy(MobileVideoServlet.java:401)
        at utilities.MobileVideoServlet.processRequest(MobileVideoServlet.java:298)
        at utilities.MobileVideoServlet.doGet(MobileVideoServlet.java:74)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
        ... 36 more
    ]]
```

Comment: thanx tailorBird for editing.. please give me solution if you know solution...

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been fixed in the latest version of GlassFish, as you can see [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20681).

Update to GlassFish 4.0.1 which in turn may solve your problem.
You can download the updated GlassFish from [here.](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/promoted/)

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can accept it as a correct answer. :)